# How to convert a text file from DOS format to UNIX format

Tags: c, file, binary, fopen, dos2unix

I am trying to make a program in C, that reads a text file and replace `\r\n` with `\n` to the same file converting the line ending from DOS to UNIX. I use `fgetc` and treat the file as a binary file. Thanks in advance.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fptr = fopen("textfile.txt", "rb+");
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("erro ficheiro \n");
        return 0;
    }

     while((ch = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF) {
          if(ch == '\r') {
           fprintf(fptr,"%c", '\n');
        } else {
         fprintf(fptr,"%c", ch);
        }
    }

    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Comment: Windows (and, historically, DOS) use both \r and \n at the end of the line, so you need to remove \r rather than replace it. And, do not try to do it in place - make a separate output file.

Comment: in binary? Do not replace \r with \n at it uses \r\n so you will end up with \n\n.  You overwrite the next char not replace the char.

Comment: You can't read from the same file you are writing to like that.  You need two file pointers — one for reading and the other for writing, both opened as binary files.  Or you might write to `stdout`, after making sure it is a binary file stream. Note that DOS (Windows) files normally have `"\r\n"` at the end of each line; you simply need to avoid printing the `'\r'` character.  What you do if you come across a `'\r'` without a `'\n'` following it, or a `'\n'` without a `'\r'` preceding it, is anyone's guess.  I'd probably just map both to `'\n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume the file uses a single byte character set, we just need to ignore all the '\r' characters when converting a text file form DOS to UNIX.

We also assume that the size of the file is less than the highest unsigned integer.

The reason we do these assumptions, is to keep the example short.

Be aware that the example below overwrites the original file, as you asked. Normally you shouldn't do this, as you can lose the contents of the original file, if an error occurs.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

// Return a negative number on failure and 0 on success.
int main()
{
    const char* filename = "textfile.txt";

    // Get the file size. We assume the filesize is not bigger than UINT_MAX.
    struct stat info;
    if (stat(filename, &info) != 0)
        return -1;
    size_t filesize = (size_t)info.st_size;

    // Allocate memory for reading the file
    char* content = (char*)malloc(filesize);
    if (content == NULL)
        return -2;

    // Open the file for reading
    FILE* fptr = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (fptr == NULL)
        return -3;

    // Read the file and close it - we assume the filesize is not bigger than UINT_MAX.
    size_t count = fread(content, filesize, 1, fptr);
    fclose(fptr);
    if (count != 1)
        return -4;

    // Remove all '\r' characters 
    size_t newsize = 0;
    for (long i = 0; i < filesize; ++i) {
        char ch = content[i];
        if (ch != '\r') {
            content[newsize] = ch;
            ++newsize;
        }
    }

    // Test if we found any
    if (newsize != filesize) {
        // Open the file for writing and truncate it.
        FILE* fptr = fopen(filename, "wb");
        if (fptr == NULL)
            return -5;

        // Write the new output to the file. Note that if an error occurs,
        // then we will lose the original contents of the file.
        if (newsize > 0)
            count = fwrite(content, newsize, 1, fptr);
        fclose(fptr);
        if (newsize > 0 && count != 1)
            return -6;
    }

    // For a console application, we don't need to free the memory allocated
    // with malloc(), but normally we should free it.

    // Success 
    return 0;
} // main()
```

To only remove '\r' followed by '\n' replace the loop with this loop:

```
    // Remove all '\r' characters followed by a '\n' character
    size_t newsize = 0;
    for (long i = 0; i < filesize; ++i) {
        char ch = content[i];
        char ch2 = (i < filesize - 1) ? content[i + 1] : 0;
        if (ch == '\r' && ch2 == '\n') {
            ch = '\n';
            ++i;
        }
        content[newsize++] = ch;
    }
```

Comment: "*We just need to ignore all the '\r' characters*" -- debatable.  This assumes that no `'\r'` characters will appear except immediately preceding a `'\n'`.  That's a relatively safe bet for a Windows text file encoded in a single-byte encoding consistent with the C implementation's runtime character set, but it's not technically correct.

Comment: Additionally, reading the whole file into memory is poor form.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It depends on the file size and the default block size and the question was about converting newlines from DOS to UNIX. If he wants several questions answered, he should create more questions.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Agreed with regards to removing '\r'. The DOS text files I have encountered with lonely '\r' characters, are usually meant for printing to an old printer, where you overwrite the same line twice, typically to underline or create bold text. I have also seen it used, to underline text on a monitor. But I haven't seen it in the wild for 25 years now.

Comment: Added snippet to also show how to only replace '\r' followed by '\n'.